# SWIG immutable std::map reference

Tags: c++, swig

I have a typedef in C++ that looks like the following:

```
typedef std::map<int, TestClass> TestClassMap;
```

I have another class that returns a `const TestClassMap&`.

Then in my interface (.i) file for SWIG, I have the following:

```
namespace std
{
    %template(TestClassMap) map<int, myNamespace::TestClass>;
}
```

This compiles fine and creates the C# library.

However, in the C# library, the function that returns a `const TestClassMap&` actually returns a TestClassMap that can be changed (is mutable). If I look at the `IsReadOnly` setting on the returned object, it is false.

From looking at SWIG documentation, it looks like there is a way to mark an object as `immutable` which I think is what I want. However, I've tried to do this and haven't had any success. I've tried each of the following:

```
%feature("immutable","1") TestClass;

%immutable TestClass;

%immutable
%template(TestClassMap) map<int, myNamespace::TestClass>;
%mutable
```

Is there some underlying reason why `const std::map<>&` cannot be made immutable? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG does not attempt to preserve const-correctness. Refer to [this rant](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn37) in the documentation:

> Although this is clearly a violation of the C++ type-system, fixing the problem doesn't seem to be worth the added implementation complexity that would be required to support it in the SWIG run-time type system. There are no plans to change this in future releases (although we'll never rule anything out entirely).
>
> The bottom line is that this particular issue does not appear to be a problem for most SWIG projects. Of course, you might want to consider using another tool if maintaining constness is the most important part of your project.